# constructing the UMP $\alpha$ = .10 size test of $H_{0}$ :$ \lambda \leq 1$ versus $H_{1}:\lambda > 1$.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Given that a sample size n =10, from a poisson($\lambda$), construct the UMP $\alpha$ = .10 size test of $H_{0}$ :$ \lambda \leq 1$  versus $\lambda > 1$

For this question I have found that we have a MLR property in T =$\sum_{i=1}^{10}X_{i}$.  In addition, using Blackwell-Girshick theorem, I can find the UMP in the form

$
\phi^{*} = 
\begin{cases}
1  \text{ if } T>k\\
\gamma \text{ if }  T =k\\
0 \text{ if } T < k
\end{cases}
$

My question is how do I find the value of k. I know that I need to find the distribution of T first, but I am stuck on how to write the working out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean Karlin-Rubin Theorem? But you find $k$ so that $E[ \phi^* ; H_0 \text{ is true}] = \alpha$.